# Check Infinite values on JS

Tags: javascript

I want to write a duINF function that will check if the value is Infinity.

```
console.log(duINF(Infinity))//true
console.log(duINF(-Infinity))//true
```

otherwise false.

How to write duINF function?  I tried:

```
const duINF = item => { 
    return (item === Infinity || item === -Infinity) 
        ? true 
        : false 
}
```

Comment: It would on ES6 supporting browsers (arrow function), also there is no point in using inline if, just return the result of the equality check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple equality check.

```
// ES5
function duINF(number) {
  return number === Infinity || number === -Infinity;
}
// ES6
const duINF = number => number === Infinity || number === -Infinity;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are running this function on a place that doesn't support ES6. If you don't know what es is, please check out [this link](https://codeburst.io/javascript-wtf-is-es6-es8-es-2017-ecmascript-dca859e4821c).

```
   // What you are trying to do is allowed on from ES6
    const duINF = (num) => num === Infinity || num === -Infinity;

    // before ES6 version
    function duINF(num) {
      return num === Infinity || num === -Infinity;
    }
```

According to the edited question, I see that you wanted to use ternary operator to have a short and clean code, but if you look closely, your ternary case already returns either true or false. You can just

```
return item === Infinity || item === -Infinity
```

Comment: That's exactly what I answered too.. :)

Comment: Haha, yeah sorry probably was writing the answer when you posted :) he can mark your as accepted no probs @Grabofus